# How can i create a JS Object that I can call any method on?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript object that I can call any method on, without having to define them.  Ideally i could call it as if it were a function, and it would call one function i've defined with the name of the function called as its argument.

So i would define an object with a `callMethod(methodName)` method, and when i called

```
thisObject.doAThing();
```

It would call `thisObject.callMethod("doAThing");`

is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't possible. If a JavaScript object doesn't have a property then you can't treat the undefined value as a method.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox at least, you can use the magic method `__noSuchMethod__` to accomplish your goal:

```
var o = {}
o.__noSuchMethod__ = function(id, args) { alert(id + args); }
o.foo(2,3) //will alert "foo" and "2,3"
```

Please note that this is not standard and is under consideration for removal, so [it will not be added to V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=264#c31).

Answer (score 0):

Original Post (sorry, should have asked this question in q comments):

I'm having trouble seeing the point. If callMethod has access to a 'doAThing' method somewhere, why couldn't you just plug that in on instantiation of the object or whenever callMethod's sources had a new method added?

Not trying to badger you. Just trying to see if maybe somewhere in the mad mad mad world of the call/apply/prototype paradigm it's possible to accomodate what you're hoping to achieve some other way.

Edit added after this comment:

> I want to create a proxy object that delegates its calls to another
>   object. – msfeldstein

Okay, prototype may be the answer then as it basically does act as a fallback for methods the object itself doesn't have. Every function has a prototype property that's just a plain vanilla object basically. When functions are used as constructors, methods and properties assigned to the constructor prototype become a fallback for constructor instances when you call properties on them that they don't have. You can add properties to that prototype object and they will effectively become available to instances that have already been created. So I'm thinking something like this in the case of associated objects:

```
//A js constructor is just a function you intend to invoke with the 'new' keyword
//use of 'this.property' will make that property public in the instance
//var effectively makes it private
//Constructors funcs differ from classes in that they don't auto-handle inheritance down to other constructors. You have to come up with a prototype merging scheme to do that.

function MyFacadeConstructor(){ //expected args are objects to associate
        var i = arguments.length; //arguments is a collection of args all funcs have
        while(i--){
            var thisObj = arguments[i];
            associateObjMethods(thisObj);
        }

        //makes it public method but allows function hoisting internally
        this.associateObjMethods = associateObjMethods;
        function associateObjMethods(obj){
            for(var x in obj){
                if(obj[x].constructor.name === 'Function'){ //normalize for <= IE8
                    MyFacadeConstructor.prototype[x] = obj[x];
                    //or if we literally want the other method firing in its original context
                    //MyFacadeConstructor.prototype[x] = function(arg){ obj[x](arg); }
                    //Not sure how you would pass same number of arguments dynamically
                    //But I believe it's possible
                    //A workaround would be to always pass/assume one arg
                    //and use object literals when multiple are needed
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function FirstNameAnnouncer(){
      this.alertFirst = function(){
          alert('Erik');
      }
    }

    var fNamer = new FirstNameAnnouncer();

    var newFacade = new MyFacadeConstructor(fNamer);

    //newFacade.alertFirst should work now;
    newFacade.alertFirst();

    //but we can also associate after the fact

    function LastNameAnnouncer(){
        this.alertLast = function(){ alert('Reppen'); }
    }

    var lNamer = new LastNameAnnouncer();

    newFacade.associateObjMethods(lNamer);

    //now newFacade.alertLast should work
    newFacade.alertLast();
```

Now, if you want the context of the calling object to matter, I would recommend an event driven interface, which is something JS is very well suited to. Let me know if there's any aspects of the facade approach you're looking for that I haven't implemented here.

Comment: It's a [common pattern in Objective-C](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MessageForwarding) that allows creation of powerful [facades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: Where does this callMethod function go hunting for the method it needs in the Objective-C approach? Does the object doing the calling matter or is it more about a shared pool of methods coming from the called object's associated or aggregate objects? I think you could go a couple ways.

Comment: I want to create a proxy object that delegates its calls to another object.

Comment: Let me know if that does it for you. I've only just started reading Design Patterns but I'm pretty excited to discover I've been doing a lot of similar stuff already in JS.

Comment: @Erik I don't think you should edit your answer and change it to somethIng completely different. This makes it hard to follow the comments. You're free to add another answer or ask a question if needed.

Comment: What I should have done was ask my question in the question comments rather than in an answer post but I haven't been "stacking" much recently. I did, however leave the original answer intact lower down in my edited answer. I'll edit again to make it more clear.

Comment: Uh, so no dice then I take it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#description) object to intercept any method call.

```js
function proxifyMethodCalls(obj) {
    const handler = {
        get(target, prop, receiver) {
            return function (...args) {
                console.log(`Intercepted '${prop}' with arguments ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
                target.callMethod(prop);
            };
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}

let obj = {
    callMethod: (methodName) => {
        console.log(`'callMethod' called with '${methodName}'`);
    }
};
obj = proxifyMethodCalls(obj);

obj.doAThing(true);
```